# Object not callable error in using Selenium with chromedriver (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is so simple but yet not working

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
def web(search):
    url = 'https://www.startpage.com'
    browser = webdriver.chrome(r'C:\Users\INDUWARA\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\chromedriver')
web("google")
```

it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\INDUWARA\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    web("google")   File "C:\Users\INDUWARA\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 4, in web
    browser = webdriver.chrome(r'C:\Users\INDUWARA\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\chromedriver') 
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

HELP!

Comment: Try: `webdriver.Chrome` with a capital **C**

Comment: Dude! thank u so much! Can't believe I spent hours trying fix a god damn capitalization issue. I hate myself !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Its not `webdriver.chrome()`. To open the browser, we need to use classes and classes names starts with capital alphabet, so use `webdriver.Chrome()`